# How can i use CalculatedMember (dimension, not measure) in Pentaho xml schema?

Tags: schema, mdx, pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I have this `MDX` query:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [CLIENT].[WITHOUT CLIENT X] AS 
    '[CLIENT].[All CLIENTs] - [CLIENT].[CLIENT X]' 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Sales] ON COLUMNS
 ,{[STORE].[All STOREs].Children} ON ROWS
FROM [Sales]
WHERE 
  CrossJoin
  (
    {[YEAR].[2015]}
   ,{[CLIENT].[WITHOUT CLIENT X]}
  );
```

This query return corect result  (All stores sales without **[CLIENT].[CLIENT X]**).

Now, I want to use this calculated member (**[CLIENT].[WITHOUT CLIENT X]**) in Saiku, OpenI, BTable or Pivot4J as a normal dimension or something like this.

For this i added in schema.xml:

```
<CalculatedMember name="WITHOUT CLIENT X" 
 formula="([CLIENT].[All CLIENTs] - [CLIENT].[CLIENT X])" hierarchy="CLIENT" parent="CLIENT" visible="true"></CalculatedMember>
```

If i run:

```
 Select [Measures].[Sales] on COLUMNS,
 {[STORE].[All STOREs].Children} ON ROWS
 from [Sales]
 WHERE CrossJoin({[YEAR].[2015]}, {[CLIENT].[WITHOUT CLIENT X]})
```

the result returned is corect, but i can't see this dimension [CLIENT].[WITHOUT CLIENT X].

In Saiku, OpenI or Pivot4J i can't find this dimension.
BTable get this dimension as **MEASURES** because of CDA (/api/olap/getCubeStructure) and result is this:

```
 {
    "type": "measure",
    "name": "WITHOUT CLIENT X",
    "caption": "WITHOUT CLIENT X]",
    "qualifiedName": "[CLIENT].[CLIENT X]",
    "memberType": "FORMULA"
  }
```

but is useless because I can't use in filter.

Do you have same answers?

Posible questions:

1. Why u use member and not named set?

Because dimension CLIENT it's huge (more than 50000) query with member run in 1 sec and with set in more than 5 minutes

2. why don't use EXCEPT?

Same as 1.

3. why not use just mdx query?

Because final report is for non-tehnic and they want to change this filter.

**UPDATE INFO**

I renamed *[CLIENT].[WITHOUT_this_CLIENT]* with *[CLIENT].[WITHOUT CLIENT X]*  and *[CLIENT].[My Special Client]* with *[CLIENT].[CLIENT X]*to avoid some confusion.

I want to filter a level in this way: add all members (CLIENT) except one (**CLIENT X**).

**The result returned is corect** when i use mdx query, because GUI OLAP clients cant read my xml schema.

I don't know where is my error.

Thank you,
Geo

**SOLVED**

For what I want (filtering one element from a big list) the answer is this:

I created another dimension, which is used just for filter.

```
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" highCardinality="false" name="CLIENT X">
    <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true">
      <Table name="SALES" schema="SALES" />
      <Level name="CLIENT X" visible="true" column="CLIENT" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
        <KeyExpression>
          <SQL dialect="oracle">
            <![CDATA[CASE WHEN CLIENT =  'CLIENT X'  THEN  'CLIENT X' ELSE 'WITHOUT CLIENT X' END]]>
          </SQL>
        </KeyExpression>
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
```

Comment: `the result returned is corect, but i can't see this dimension [CLIENT].[WITHOUT_this_CLIENT]` - Can you edit your answer with the output and let us know what you mean by this? Also, what is your actual intention?

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining your member correctly. ie. The parent member must be the fully qualified name of the parent of the newly created member, not the level's name. Read [this](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/xml_schema.php#CalculatedMember) carefully and you'll figure it out.

Comment: i already read that, but i don't really figure it. I have 
  `MEMBER [CLIENT].[WITHOUT_this_CLIENT] AS   '[CLIENT].[All CLIENTs] - [CLIENT].[My Special Client]'`  and i want to convert in schema: `<CalculatedMember name="WITHOUT_this_CLIENT" 
 formula="([CLIENT].[All CLIENTs] - [CLIENT].[My Special Client])" hierarchy="CLIENT" parent="CLIENT" visible="true"></CalculatedMember>`